# How get only woven classes by AspectJ?

Tags: aspectj

How one can get only the woven classes by aspectj in an output folder? Or at least the list of woven classes?

Answer (score 1):

An easy and elegant solution is to use the [AJDT plugin](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/) for Eclipse.

With AspectJ nature activated, you can right click on an advice and see a list of all the places that advice will be woven in.

[image: AspectJ advises]

The AJDT plugin also support a cross reference view that you can read more about in this [introductory article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-AJDT/article.html).